# longjmp(buffer, 0) doesn't return 0

Tags: c, setjmp

I'm trying to do something simple using setjmp/longjmp: asking a user to press Enter many times and if the user inserts something else it will restarts the process using longjmp.

I'm using a counter to check if it works, this counter is 0 at start but when longjmp is used the counter restarts at 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
jmp_buf buffer;
char inputBuffer[512];

void handle_interrupt(int signal) {
    longjmp(buffer, 0);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int counter = 0;
    counter = setjmp(buffer); // Save the initial state.

    printf("Counter: %d\n", counter);

    printf("\nWelcome in the jump game, press enter (nothing else!): \n");
    while (fgets(inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), stdin)) {
        if (*inputBuffer == '\n') { // If user press Enter
            counter++;
            printf("%d\n\n", counter);
            printf("Again: \n");
        } else {
            handle_interrupt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
pc3:Assignement 3 ArmandG$ ./tictockforever
Counter: 0

Welcome in the jump game, press enter (nothing else!): 

1

Again: 

2

Again: 
StackOverflow
Counter: 1

Welcome in the jump game, press enter (nothing else!): 

2

Again:
```

I know that this code is silly, I'm just trying to use setjmp/longjmp on a simple example.

Comment: what behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: setjmp's returned value should be the parameter passed to longjmp, so I except that setjmp(buffer) set counter to 0.

Comment: @ArmandG. longjmp (0) behaves as if you called longjmp (1) according to the C Standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`setjmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) only returns 0 when returning the first time, directly.

In any other cases, it returns whatever you passed to [`longjmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html), *unless you passed 0*:
In that case it returns 1.

Answer (score 4):

You need to download a copy of the C Standard (Google for "C11 Draft Standard" for example) and read the documentation of setjmp / longjmp very, very carefully. setjmp is not a function like others. Your use of setjmp is absolutely illegal. About the *only* legal way to use it is something like

```
if (setjmp (...)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MSC22-C.+Use+the+setjmp%28%29,+longjmp%28%29+facility+securely (just googled it)

Comment: +1 That's right. It might be inside of a conditional construct. But it can also be `switch`.